# screen orientation locks in the mode in which the app is opened

Tags: android, motorola

On Moto G6 plus device - the screen orientation is getting locked in the orientation in which the user has opened the app and the same mode screen ( portrait or landscape) is loaded even when the user changes the device orientation.

i.e, If the app is opened in landscape mode , it show landscape mode screens only even if the orientation is later changed to portrait mode and vice-versa.

Note : This behavior is seen only on Moto G6 plus device only and not on any other device.

Any help would be appreciated.

Manifest code -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:name=".app.AppContext"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".uilayer.splashscreen.Splash_Activity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- Start: WifiList activities -->
        <activity
            android:name=".uilayer.wifilist.WifiList_Activity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity android:name=".osinterfacelayer.DisabledWifiActivity" />
        <!-- End: WifiList activities -->


        <!-- Start: Initial screen activities -->
        <activity
            android:name=".uilayer.initial.InitialScreen_Activity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <!-- End: Initial screen activities -->


        <!-- Start: Initial screen DragAndDrop activities -->
        <activity
            android:name=".uilayer.initial.draganddrop.PreviewInitialScreenActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.FullScreen.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".uilayer.initial.draganddrop.FunctionsListActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <!-- End: Initial screen DragAndDrop activities -->


        <!-- Start: ILevel Activities -->
        <activity
            android:name=".uilayer.ilvl.ILevel_Activity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <!-- End: ILevel Activities -->


        <!-- Start: LiftAxleControl activities -->
        <activity
            android:name=".uilayer.liftaxlecontrol.LiftAxleControl_Activity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <!-- End: LiftAxleControl activities -->


        <!-- Start: Camera activities -->
        <activity
            android:name=".uilayer.camera.Camera_Activity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <!-- End: Camera activities -->


        <!-- Start: TPMS activities -->
        <activity
            android:name=".uilayer.tpms.TPMS_Activity"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".uilayer.tpms.TIP_TPMS_Activity"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <!-- End: TPMS activities -->


        <!-- Start: Cover Control activities -->
        <activity
            android:name=".uilayer.covercontrol.CoverControl_Activity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <!-- Start: Cover control activities -->


        <!-- Start: UnderRunProtection activities -->
        <activity
            android:name=".uilayer.urp.UnderRunProtection_Activity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <!-- End: UnderRunProtection activities -->


        <!-- Start: RLF activities -->
        <activity
            android:name=".uilayer.rlf.RLF_Activity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <!-- End: RLF activities -->


        <!-- Start: HydroulicTailGate activities -->

        <activity android:name=".uilayer.hydraulictailgate.HydraulicTailgate_Activity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"></activity>
          />
        <!-- End: HydroulicTailGate activities -->


        <!-- Start: OnboardWeighingIndication activities -->
        <activity
            android:name=".uilayer.owi.OnboardWeighingIndication_Activity"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".uilayer.owi.OWICalibrationMode_Activity"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".uilayer.owi.OWIBasicMode_Activity"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".uilayer.owi.OWIAdvancedMode_Activity"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".uilayer.owi.OWICalibrationModePneumaticUnladen_Activity"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".uilayer.owi.OWICalibrationModePneumaticLaden_Activity"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".uilayer.owi.OWICalibrationModeHydraulicSensor_Activity"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".uilayer.owi.OWICalibrationModeSensorCrosscheck_Activity"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <!-- End: OnboardWeighingIndication activities -->


        <!-- Start: Info activities -->
        <activity
            android:name=".uilayer.info.Info_Activity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <!-- End: Info activities -->


        <!-- Start: Control Release activities -->
        <activity
            android:name=".uilayer.controlrelease.ControlRelease_Activity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <!-- End: Control Release activities -->


        <!-- Start: Moving screen activities -->
        <activity
            android:name=".uilayer.movingscreen.MovingScreen_Activity"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <!-- End: Moving screen activities -->


        <!-- Start: Config Not Ready Activity -->
        <activity
            android:name=".uilayer.alert.ConfigNotReady_Activity"
            android:configChanges="orientation" />
        <!-- End: Config Not Ready Activity -->

        <activity
            android:name=".uilayer.alert.ConnectionLost_Activity"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_connection_lost"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Translucent" />

        <!-- Start: ITAPConnectionChange Activity -->
        <activity
            android:name=".osinterfacelayer.ITAPConnectionChange"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Translucent" />
        <!-- End: ITAPConnectionChange Activity -->


        <!-- Start: Settings activities -->
        <activity
            android:name=".uilayer.settings.Settings_Activity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <!-- End: Settings activities -->


        <!-- Start: Status activities -->
        <activity
            android:name=".uilayer.status.FunctionStatus_Activity"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <!-- End: Status activities -->


        <!-- Start: ADL activities -->
        <activity
            android:name=".uilayer.adl.ADL_Activity"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <!-- End: ADL activities -->


        <!-- Start: Service -->
        <!-- End: Service -->

        <activity
            android:name=".uilayer.initial.TIP_InitialScreen_Activity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".uilayer.camera.CameraFeedActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".uilayer.walkingfloor.WalkingFloorActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".uilayer.walkingfloor.WalkingFloorCoverControlActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".uilayer.walkingfloor.WalkingFloorLoadUnloadActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".uilayer.info.DetailDTCActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity android:name=".uilayer.info.HTMLPageActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" ></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

And Motorola G6 plus is running on android 8.0.0

Comment: Post your manifest code, and what is android version of the Moto G6 plus?

Comment: Post your manifest code and activity code